# need to create report showing usage over time

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a report (line graph really) to show application usage over a given period of time.

I have a SQL database that contains the following information I'll use:

```
- Application Name
- Application Version
- Start Time
- End Time (if still running, will == null)
```

I have other variables that I'll use to manipulate the data here and there, but my primary concern is the start / end time:
What I'm looking for is basically a line graph for a given period of time (using DateTimePicker, but that's simple to do), which will show how many clients are running an application over time.

So, basically only focusing on valid start / end times, how can I display this in a line graph?  I've searched everywhere, and I've done reports before, but can't figure out how to turn this into a line graph.

EDIT:
Sample SQL Query:

```
SELECT REPORTING_CLIENT_INFORMATION.host_name, 
       APPLICATION_USAGE.start_time,
       APPLICATION_USAGE.app_name, 
       APPLICATION_USAGE.app_version, 
       APPLICATION_USAGE.end_time, 
       APPLICATION_USAGE.shutdown_state
FROM   APPLICATION_USAGE 
INNER JOIN REPORTING_CLIENT_INFORMATION 
        ON APPLICATION_USAGE.host_id = REPORTING_CLIENT_INFORMATION.host_id
WHERE (APPLICATION_USAGE.start_time <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND
      (REPORTING_CLIENT_INFORMATION.host_name LIKE N'%DNCS%') AND
      (APPLICATION_USAGE.end_time >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102) OR
                      APPLICATION_USAGE.end_time IS NULL)
```

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C Sharp".

Comment: Apologies - I write in it all the time, but when using Google, c# doesn't work well, you have to use c sharp.. and I just finished googling this like crazy lol

Comment: @JustinMangum, Which flavour of SQL (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer etc) are you using?

Comment: @MarkBannister MS SQL - This is actually for Microsoft App-V - I want better reports than those that are on the management server

Comment: I already have a sample query, just need to figure out how to display the information I receive

Comment: where do you want to show the report? in crystal report or in a winform??

Comment: -1 for using crystal reports...just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula that calculate duration:

```
  //{@duration}
  If Isnull({APPLICATION_USAGE.end_time}) Then
    DateDiff("s", {APPLICATION_USAGE.start_time}, (DataDate + DataTime))
  Else
    DateDiff("s", {APPLICATION_USAGE.start_time}, {APPLICATION_USAGE.end_time})
```

Insert a cross-tab in the Report Header section.  Add the app_name field to the 'Rows' box, then do the same for the app_version field.  Next add the {@duration} field to the 'Summarized Fields' box.  Make sure that the calculation is 'Sum'.

Add a chart to the Report Header section.  Select the 'Cross-Tab' button.  Select app_name from the 'on change of' list, app_version from the 'subdivided by' list, and {@duration} from the 'Show' list.  Click OK, then preview the report.